An integral inequality for a bounded function integrated against its continuous derivative
Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and $a:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty[$ is a continuous function. Assume also that $f$ is bounded and that $a f^{\prime}$ is integrable. Does there exist a constant $C$ independent of $f$ such that
$$\left|\int a f f^{\prime}\right|\leq C \|f\|_{\infty} \left|\int a f^{\prime}\right|.$$
If $f$ is monotone, the inequality holds true easily since $f^{\prime}$ does not change sign then and we have $\left|\int a f^{\prime}\right|=\int a |f^{\prime}|$.

Did you use the fact that $ff'=\frac  1 2 (f^{2})'$?

No.  It's entirely possible to have $\int a f' \; dx = 0$ while $\int a f f' \; dx \ne 0$.  For example, try
$$f(x) = \left(4 x^{3}+x^{2}-3 x \right) {\mathrm e}^{-x^{2}}, \ a(x) = {\mathrm e}^{-x^2} $$
